# Como prever próximo resulta de um array dentro do foreach

Tags: php

Bom tenho o seguinte código:

```
    // Aqui eu recebos os produtos da API
$produtos = array(
    array('cod' => 8, 'nome' => 'Produto teste 8', 'grupo' => 'Doces', 'valor' => 1007),
    array('cod' => 9, 'nome' => 'Produto teste 9', 'grupo' => 'Doces', 'valor' => 1050),
    array('cod' => 10, 'nome' => 'Produto teste 10', 'grupo' => 'Doces', 'valor' => 1050),
    array('cod' => 1, 'nome' => 'Produto teste 1', 'grupo' => 'Farinha', 'valor' => 1400),
    array('cod' => 2, 'nome' => 'Produto teste 2', 'grupo' => 'Farinha', 'valor' => 170),
    array('cod' => 4, 'nome' => 'Produto teste 4', 'grupo' => 'Frios', 'valor' => 1600),
    array('cod' => 5, 'nome' => 'Produto teste 5', 'grupo' => 'Frios', 'valor' => 1800),
    array('cod' => 6, 'nome' => 'Produto teste 6', 'grupo' => 'Frios', 'valor' => 1070),
    array('cod' => 7, 'nome' => 'Produto teste 7', 'grupo' => 'Frios', 'valor' => 1070),
    array('cod' => 11, 'nome' => 'Produto teste 11', 'grupo' => 'Frios', 'valor' => 1060),
    array('cod' => 3, 'nome' => 'Produto teste 3', 'grupo' => 'Limpeza', 'valor' => 1080)
);

//OBS o array esta em ordem alfabétida dos grupos


// Aqui eu monto o HTML
?>
<table>

    <tbody>
        <?php

        // Inicía variável
        $categoriaAtual = null;

        // Navega pelos elementos do array
        foreach ($produtos as $c) {

            // Verifica grupo
            if ($categoriaAtual !== $c['grupo']) {

                $categoriaAtual = $c['grupo'];

                ?>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="100%">
                            <b><i><?=$c['grupo']?></i><b>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Cód. Produto</td>
                        <td>Produto</td>
                        <td>Valor</td>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <?php
            }
            ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?= $c['cod'] ?></td>
                <td><?= $c['nome'] ?></td>
                <td><?= $c['valor'] ?></td>
            </tr>
            <?php
        }
        ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

O resulta é esse:

```html
Doces
Cód. Produto Produto Valor
8 Produto teste 8 1007
9 Produto teste 9 1050
10 Produto teste 10 1050
Farinha
Cód. Produto Produto Valor
1 Produto teste 1 1400
2 Produto teste 2 170
Frios
Cód. Produto Produto Valor
4 Produto teste 4 1600
5 Produto teste 5 1800
6 Produto teste 6 1070
7 Produto teste 7 1070
11 Produto teste 11 1060
Limpeza
Cód. Produto Produto Valor
3 Produto teste 3 1080
```

Bom quero adicionar no final de cada grupo o total, pensei em fazer isso detectando quando é o último produto do grupo e adicionando uma `<tr>`

Alguém sabe como fazer isso? Ou até mesmo de uma forma mais prática?

Comment: E qual seria a necessidade disto? Pq se a necessidade for o que eu imagino então a estratégia seria 2 loops, mas não posso afirmar sem detalhes, o bom de explicar isto na pergunta é que as vezes você pensa que precisa de algo que na verdade você não precisa e assim podemos dar sugestões melhores que atendam ao seu problema.

Comment: Editei a pergunta com mais detalhes

Comment: Você poderia fazer o `foreach` com `as $i => $functionario` e exibir o salário de `$functionarios[$i+1]`, com as devidas condições, mas também não entendi muito bem o objetivo, principalmente em relação ao grupo do produto sendo o exemplo com funcionários.

Comment: Você poderia dar um exemplo real? Acredito que duas pessoas responderam a pergunta sem esclarecer sua dúvida. Já que você fala em produtos agrupados (portanto entendo que existam múltiplos grupos), mas o seu código trata uma lista de funcionários sem agrupamento...

Comment: @bfavaretto de fata é verdade, editei a pergunta com um exemplo real

Comment: Se é o total, então simplesmente iterar não vai resolver totalmente, tem que somar, mas dá pra fazer em um for unico, vou tentar fazer aqui e colocar na resposta

Comment: Vou retirar a resposta por enquanto pois não tenho como analisar no momento. Quando estiver mais tranquilo dou um feedback.

Comment: Hugo e @AugustoVasques editei https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/435115/3635, simplifiquei pra um IF, a parte importante, q agora é evidente, era a soma dos valores, tinha problema na marcação do HTML, fiz uns ajustes, sobre semantica eu não sei se ele esta OK, mas a lógica sem precisar de 2 "for"s deu pra ajustar, vou comentar o código pra ficar mais claro.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Antes de responder preciso lhe alertar, os teus THEADs estão sendo gerados no mesmo nivel que os demais TRs que não pertencem aos THEADs propriamente, deveria haver um TBODY em cada, mas o problema principal é que você colocou tudo dentro de TBODY, mas é provável que o renderizador "corrija".

O seu problema vai além de adicionar **uma linha**, ele tem que somar os valores, tendo isto em mente é necessário 2 variaveis auxiliares, meio que uma você já fez `$categoriaAtual = null;`, mas falta a da soma.

Outra coisa, se vai misturar tanto HTML com PHP eu pessoalmente optaria por usar este formato:

```
<?php if (): ?>
html
<?php endif; ?>
```

e

```
<?php for/while/foreach (): ?>
<?php endfor/endwhile/endforeach; ?>
```

Não tem ganho de performance, a questão melhorar apenas um pouco como você enxerga o código, no geral deve ficar assim:

```
<?php

$produtos = array(
    array('cod' => 8, 'nome' => 'Produto teste 8', 'grupo' => 'Doces', 'valor' => 1007),
    array('cod' => 9, 'nome' => 'Produto teste 9', 'grupo' => 'Doces', 'valor' => 1050),
    array('cod' => 10, 'nome' => 'Produto teste 10', 'grupo' => 'Doces', 'valor' => 1050),
    array('cod' => 1, 'nome' => 'Produto teste 1', 'grupo' => 'Farinha', 'valor' => 1400),
    array('cod' => 2, 'nome' => 'Produto teste 2', 'grupo' => 'Farinha', 'valor' => 170),
    array('cod' => 4, 'nome' => 'Produto teste 4', 'grupo' => 'Frios', 'valor' => 1600),
    array('cod' => 5, 'nome' => 'Produto teste 5', 'grupo' => 'Frios', 'valor' => 1800),
    array('cod' => 6, 'nome' => 'Produto teste 6', 'grupo' => 'Frios', 'valor' => 1070),
    array('cod' => 7, 'nome' => 'Produto teste 7', 'grupo' => 'Frios', 'valor' => 1070),
    array('cod' => 11, 'nome' => 'Produto teste 11', 'grupo' => 'Frios', 'valor' => 1060),
    array('cod' => 3, 'nome' => 'Produto teste 3', 'grupo' => 'Limpeza', 'valor' => 1080)
);
?>

<table>
    <?php
    // Inicía variável
    $categoriaAtual = null;
    $categoriaTotal = 0;
    ?>

    <?php foreach ($produtos as $produto): ?>

        <?php if ($categoriaAtual !== $produto['grupo']): ?>


        <?php
        // Entra neste IF se não for o primeiro produto, devido ao NULL inicial
        if ($categoriaAtual !== null):
        ?>

        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">Total</td>
            <td><?=$categoriaTotal?></td>
        </tr>

        <?php
        // Quando muda de categoria é necessário "resetar" a soma para poder começar novamente
        $categoriaTotal = 0;
        ?>

        </tbody>

        <?php endif; ?>

        <thead>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="100%">
                    <b><i><?=$produto['grupo']?></i><b>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Cód. Produto</td>
                <td>Produto</td>
                <td>Valor</td>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <?php endif; ?>

        <?php
        //Seta o valor sempre, para o proximo ciclo poder saber se o grupo mudou
        $categoriaAtual = $produto['grupo'];

        //Soma os valores a cada ciclo
        $categoriaTotal += $produto['valor'];
        ?>

        <tr>
            <td><?= $produto['cod'] ?></td>
            <td><?= $produto['nome'] ?></td>
            <td><?= $produto['valor'] ?></td>
        </tr>

    <?php endforeach; ?>

    <?php
    //Nesta parte o foreach já terminou, mas é necessário pegar o total
    //do ultimo grpo e fechar o TBODY e isto só pode ocorrer se tiver ao
    //menos um produto no array, se tiver zero nem entra neste IF
    if ($categoriaAtual !== null):
    ?>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">Total</td>
            <td><?=$categoriaTotal?></td>
        </tr>

        </tbody>
    <?php endif; ?>

</table>
```

Para ver o resultado coloque no StackSnipet abaixo:

```css
table {
    width: 100%;
}

td {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

thead {
    background: #00f;
    color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<table>
    
    
                
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="100%">
                    <b><i>Doces</i><b>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Cód. Produto</td>
                <td>Produto</td>
                <td>Valor</td>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        
        
        <tr>
            <td>8</td>
            <td>Produto teste 8</td>
            <td>1007</td>
        </tr>

    
        
        
        <tr>
            <td>9</td>
            <td>Produto teste 9</td>
            <td>1050</td>
        </tr>

    
        
        
        <tr>
            <td>10</td>
            <td>Produto teste 10</td>
            <td>1050</td>
        </tr>

    
                
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">Total</td>
            <td>3107</td>
        </tr>

        
        </tbody>

        
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="100%">
                    <b><i>Farinha</i><b>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Cód. Produto</td>
                <td>Produto</td>
                <td>Valor</td>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        
        
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>Produto teste 1</td>
            <td>1400</td>
        </tr>

    
        
        
        <tr>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>Produto teste 2</td>
            <td>170</td>
        </tr>

    
                
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">Total</td>
            <td>1570</td>
        </tr>

        
        </tbody>

        
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="100%">
                    <b><i>Frios</i><b>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Cód. Produto</td>
                <td>Produto</td>
                <td>Valor</td>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        
        
        <tr>
            <td>4</td>
            <td>Produto teste 4</td>
            <td>1600</td>
        </tr>

    
        
        
        <tr>
            <td>5</td>
            <td>Produto teste 5</td>
            <td>1800</td>
        </tr>

    
        
        
        <tr>
            <td>6</td>
            <td>Produto teste 6</td>
            <td>1070</td>
        </tr>

    
        
        
        <tr>
            <td>7</td>
            <td>Produto teste 7</td>
            <td>1070</td>
        </tr>

    
        
        
        <tr>
            <td>11</td>
            <td>Produto teste 11</td>
            <td>1060</td>
        </tr>

    
                
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">Total</td>
            <td>6600</td>
        </tr>

        
        </tbody>

        
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="100%">
                    <b><i>Limpeza</i><b>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Cód. Produto</td>
                <td>Produto</td>
                <td>Valor</td>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        
        
        <tr>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>Produto teste 3</td>
            <td>1080</td>
        </tr>

    
            <tr>
            <td colspan="2">Total</td>
            <td>1080</td>
        </tr>

        </tbody>
    
</table>
```

### Resposta antes da edição

<s>Se você sabe a quantidade de itens que um array/iterador possuem, então você sabe quando vai ser o ultimo na verdade, antes mesmo do `foreach` você e o "script" já sabem quando deve ser o último, basta incrementar uma variável a partir do zero assim:</s>

```
<?php

$funcionarios = array(
    array('id' => 1, 'nome' => 'João', 'salario' => 5000),
    array('id' => 22, 'nome' => 'Mauro', 'salario' => 560),
    array('id' => 8, 'nome' => 'Alice', 'salario' => 4300),
);

$j = count($funcionarios);

for ($i = 0; $i < $j; ++$i) {

    if ($j - 1 === $i) {
        //Aqui vai a tal linha sobre o ultimo resultado
    }

    $funcionario = $funcionarios[$i];

    echo $funcionario["nome"]." $".$funcionario["salario"]."<br>\n";

    // Aqui quero colocar o proximo resultado
}
```

Agora se os dados vieram de um banco, então suponho que usou `fetchAll` do `PDO` suporta o count e no foreach com PDO dá pra aplicar dentro do escopo um `++$i`

Se for mysqli API pode usar [`num_rows()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php) (ou `SELECT FOUND_ROWS();` em uma query, dependendo do que fez) antes de iterar.

Comment: Vejam o comentário que deixei agora na pergunta. Acredito que a dúvida real seja outra (conforme o último parágrafo da pergunta). cc @AugustoVasques

Comment: @bfavaretto é só colocar o IF antes então. Falta de atenção minha.

Comment: Parece que ele quer agrupar os dados no fundo

Comment: @bfavaretto pois é, e também tinha a soma dos valores, ele não havia informado com clareza, editei e deixei um exemplo da saída em HTML.

Comment: Muito bom, consegui fazer exatamente o que eu queria.